# MYSQL - Joining two query into one

Tags: mysql

I would like to combine two query so it would look like the desire output below:

QUERY1

```
SELECT 

count(distinct case when YEAR(from_unixtime(t2.dateline)) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
  then t1.ticketmaskid end) AS TYear, 
count(distinct case when WEEK(from_unixtime(t2.dateline)) = WEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
  then t1.ticketmaskid end) AS TWeek, 
count(distinct case when MONTH(from_unixtime(t2.dateline)) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
  then t1.ticketmaskid end) AS TMonth 

FROM swtickets t1 JOIN swticketauditlogs t2 ON t1.ticketid = t2.ticketid 

WHERE FIND_IN_SET (t1.departmenttitle,'Support') AND t2.actionmsg LIKE '%Email Queue: abc.com.my%';
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| TYear | TWeek | TMonth |
+-------+-------+--------+
|     1 |     1 |      1 |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

QUERY2

```
SELECT 

count(distinct case when YEAR(from_unixtime(t2.dateline)) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
  then t1.ticketmaskid end) AS TYear, 
count(distinct case when WEEK(from_unixtime(t2.dateline)) = WEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
  then t1.ticketmaskid end) AS TWeek, 
count(distinct case when MONTH(from_unixtime(t2.dateline)) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
  then t1.ticketmaskid end) AS TMonth 

FROM swtickets t1 JOIN swticketauditlogs t2 ON t1.ticketid = t2.ticketid 

WHERE FIND_IN_SET (t1.departmenttitle,'Support') AND t2.actionmsg LIKE '%Email Queue: abc.com.sg%';
```

Output

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| TYear | TWeek | TMonth |
+-------+-------+--------+
|     2 |     1 |      1 |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

I would like to have the following result

```
+----------+-------+-------+--------+
|Domain    | TYear | TWeek | TMonth |
+----------+-------+-------+--------+
|abc.com.my|     2 |     1 |      1 |
+----------+-------+-------+--------+
|abc.com.sg|     1 |     1 |      1 |
+----------+-------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: where is the result ?

Comment: I have issue paste the result

Comment: <pre>
+----------+-------+-------+--------+
|Domain    | TYear | TWeek | TMonth |
+----------+-------+-------+--------+
|abc.com.my|     2 |     1 |      1 |
+----------+-------+-------+--------+
|abc.com.sg|     1 |     1 |      1 |
+----------+-------+-------+--------+
</pre>

Comment: anyone can help me paste on the result above. I have issue saving it

Comment: can i have more than 1 condition for "SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.actionmsg, 'Email Queue: ', -1) as Domain"? eg.  Email Queue: or domain Queue:

Answer (score 0):

If the 2 queries return the same table's structure...
You can join the 2 queries by using `UNION`

```
QUERY1
UNION
QUERY2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common operation in SQL called aggregation.  You need to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.actionmsg, 'Email Queue: ', -1) as Domain,
       count(distinct case when YEAR(from_unixtime(t2.dateline)) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
                           then t1.ticketmaskid end) AS TYear, 
       count(distinct case when WEEK(from_unixtime(t2.dateline)) = WEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
                           then t1.ticketmaskid end) AS TWeek, 
       count(distinct case when MONTH(from_unixtime(t2.dateline)) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
                          then t1.ticketmaskid end) AS TMonth 
FROM   swtickets t1
 JOIN  swticketauditlogs t2 ON t1.ticketid = t2.ticketid 
WHERE  FIND_IN_SET(t1.departmenttitle, 'Support')
  AND  t2.actionmsg RLIKE 'Email Queue: abc\.com\.(my|sg)'
GROUP  BY Domain
```

You could extend this to all possible domains by not restricting the `actionmsg`:

```
WHERE  FIND_IN_SET(t1.departmenttitle, 'Support')
  AND  t2.actionmsg RLIKE 'Email Queue: abc\.com'
```

Then you would get a separate row for each possible domain.

Comment: wow. it works. may i know what is RLIKE? It works the same as LIKE?

Comment: if i use WITH ROLLUP, how do i replace null at the bottom with total?

Comment: You're welcome.  `RLIKE` tests strings for matches against [regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html).  The `NULL` value in `WITH ROLLUP` is part of MySQL's implementation; the only way to print something different is to wrap the entire query inside another query specifically for that purpose or to use a programming language to query the DB and process the output.

Comment: can i have more than 1 condition for "SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.actionmsg, 'Email Queue: ', -1) as Domain"? eg.  Email Queue: or domain Queue:

Comment: Sure, you could do a big `CASE` statement for that first field, extracting different substrings depending on the contents of `actionmsg`.  Presumably you would also have to augment the regular expression in the `RLIKE` comparison to allow for those other possibilities as well.